# Javascript code reduction on sort with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with data similar to this but with more fields to sort from:

```
const shirts= [
    {
      type: "T-shirt",
      size: "L",
      color: "Black",
    },
    {
      type: "Dress Shirt",
      size: "S",
      color: "Brown",
    },
    {
      type: "Sweatshirt",
      size: "M",
      color: "Red",
    }, 
    {
      type: "Polo",
      size: "XS",
      color: "Pink",
    },  
    ...]
```

I have a sort function that works differently based on what is selected, for example if the user sorts by size it needs to go from XS to XL but any other option it needs to sort alphabetically. This is what I have:

```
//sort is the option the user decided to sort by
SortedShirts(sort,shirts){
        var newShirtArray=[];
        var size1=0;
        var size2=0;
        if(sort === "type"){
            newShirtArray= shirts.sort(function(shirt1,shirt2){
                if (shirt1.type> shirt2.type){ 
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return -1;
                } 
            });
        }
        else if(sort === "color"){
            newShirtArray = shirts.sort(function(shirt1,shirt2){
                if (shirt1.color > shirt2.color){ 
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return -1;
                } 
            });
        }
        else if(sort === "size"){
            newShirtArray = shirts.sort(function(shirt1,shirt2){
                if(shirt1.size==="XS"){
                    size1=0;
                }
                else if(shirt1.size==="S"){
                    size1=1;
                }
                else if(shirt1.size==="M"){
                    size1=2;
                }
                else if(shirt1.size==="L"){
                    size1=3;
                }
                else if(shirt1.size==="XL"){
                    size1=4;
                }

                if(shirt2.size==="XS"){
                    size2=0;
                }
                else if(shirt2.size==="S"){
                    size2=1;
                }
                else if(shirt2.size==="M"){
                    size2=2;
                }
                else if(shirt2.size==="L"){
                    size2=3;
                }
                else if(shirt2.size==="XL"){
                    size2=4;
                }


                if (size1 > size2){ 
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    return -1;
                } 
            });
        }
```

This seems repetitive to me because type and color sort the same way just with a different field and I feel I can put that into one sort but I am unsure on how to do it. I'm wondering if there is something like this

```
if(sort === "type" || sort === "color"){
     newShirtArray= shirts.sort(function(shirt1,shirt2){
           if (shirt1.fieldOf(sort) > shirt2.fieldOf(sort)){ 
               return 1;
           }
           else{
               return -1;
           } 
     });
}
```

Or another way to reduce my code?

Comment: what is the order for the types and the colors?

Comment: is it just their lexicographic order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use a `switch` statement:

```js
switch (sort) {
    case 'color':
    case 'type':
        newShirtArray = shirts.sort(/* ... */);
        break;

    case 'size':
        newShirtArray = shirts.sort(/* ... */);
        break;
}
```

2. For converting you shirt size to number, you can use an object:

```js
const ShirtSizes = {
    XS: 0, S: 1, M: 2, L: 3, XL: 4,
};
const shirt1Size = ShirtSizes[shirt1.size];
```

3. If your environment allows this, use more concise ES2015 arrow functions:

```js
case 'size':
    newShirtArray = shirts.sort((s1, s2) => ShirtSizes[s1.size] - ShirtSizes[s2.size]);
    break;
```

4. For `type` and `color`, as you guessed, you can use this:

```js
case 'color':
case 'type':
    newShirtArray = shirts.sort((s1, s2) => {
        if (s1[sort] > s2[sort]) {
            return 1;
        } else if (s1[sort] < s2[sort]) {
            return -1;
        } else {
           return 0;
        }
    });
```

I hope this will help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can access JSON object's key using bracket.

```
const shirts = [
    {
        type: "T-shirt",
        size: "L",
        color: "Black",
    },
    {
        type: "Dress Shirt",
        size: "S",
        color: "Brown",
    },
    {
        type: "Sweatshirt",
        size: "M",
        color: "Red",
    },
    {
        type: "Polo",
        size: "XS",
        color: "Pink",
    },
]

function SortedShirts(sort, shirts) {
    var newShirtArray = [];
    var size1 = 0;
    var size2 = 0;
    if (sort === "type" || sort === "color") {
        newShirtArray = shirts.sort(function (shirt1, shirt2) {
            if (shirt1[sort] > shirt2[sort]) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        });
    }
    else if (sort === "size") {
        const sizes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']
        newShirtArray = shirts.sort(function (shirt1, shirt2) {
            const size1 = sizes.indexOf(shirt1.size)
            const size2 = sizes.indexOf(shirt2.size)

            if (size1 > size2) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        });
    }
}
```